# How to access the calculated small values of animation in Core Animation?

Tags: swift, cocoa, core-animation

I am using this below code for my animation:

```
let animation = CABasicAnimation()
animation.keyPath = "position.x"
animation.fromValue = 0
animation.toValue = 300
animation.timingFunction = .init(name: .easeInEaseOut)
animation.duration = 2


nsView.layer?.add(animation, forKey: "basic")
```

If you look to codes you see in 2sec we are changing from 0 to 300, I want to get access to the calculated values in between like: `0.0, 0.2, 0.3, ..., 300.0` with **CABasicAnimation** so how can I do this?

Comment: How do you want to get the values? Do you want to give it a time (as a number between 0 and 2), and it spits out a number between 0 and 300? Or do you want to get the *current* value of the animation, as the animation is happening?

Comment: Because I am using `easeInEaseOut` we cannot calculate them like you said, we have to use the second option you said, I want access the values or the current values of animation when animation happen from 0 to 300

Comment: If you just want to get the current value, you can just do `layer.presentation().xxx`, where `xxx` is the thing you are animating. You can still calculate the value without the animation running though. It's just a bezier curve.

Comment: Wow, there was so many information in a comment, I would love to know about the second way as well, could you answer that please? also about `layer.presentation()` how can I simply print them?

Comment: For example if I just use this `print(redView.layer?.presentation()?.frame)` this would just print current animation vale, But I would like the all values from 0 to 300 when the animation happens like: 0, 0.1, 0.21, 0.34, ...

Comment: You want the value at each frame of the animation? That's a weird requirement - this might be a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). But I guess hooking up a `CADisplayLink` should get you each frame.

Comment: Oh yes, I think that might also help, I would love to have your answer about bezier cure also about `CADisplayLink`, if you have time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an ongoing animation, you can get its progress through the [`presentation()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410744-presentation) layer by accessing the property that you are animating. If you want every frame of the animation, you can hook up a [`CVDisplayLink`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corevideo/cvdisplaylink-k0k) (for macOS) or [`CADisplayLink`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cadisplaylink) (for iOS).

Example code:

```
var displayLink: CVDisplayLink!
//var displayLink: CADisplayLink!

func someFunctionThatTriggersTheAnimation() {
    let animation = CABasicAnimation()
    // let's say we are animating position.x
    animation.keyPath = "position.x"
    animation.fromValue = 0
    animation.toValue = 300
    animation.timingFunction = .init(name: .easeInEaseOut)
    animation.duration = 2

    // Please conform self to CAAnimationDelegate!
    animation.delegate = self
    button.layer?.add(animation, forKey: "basic")
}

// CAAnimationDelegate methods:
func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
    CVDisplayLinkStop(displayLink)
}

func animationDidStart(_ anim: CAAnimation) {

    // CVDisplayLink is a bit of a hassle to use in Swift :(
    CVDisplayLinkCreateWithCGDisplay(CGMainDisplayID(), &displayLink)
    withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &button!) { pointer in
        CVDisplayLinkSetOutputCallback(displayLink, { _, _, _, _, _, buttonPointer in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print(buttonPointer!.assumingMemoryBound(to: NSButton.self).pointee.layer!.presentation()!.position.x)
            }
            return 1
        }, pointer)
    }
    CVDisplayLinkStart(displayLink)
}

/*
CADisplayLink would look like this:

func animationDidStop(_ anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
    displayLink.invalidate()
}

func animationDidStart(_ anim: CAAnimation) {
    displayLink = CADisplayLink(target: self, selector: #selector(printAnimationProgress))
    displayLink.add(to: .main, forMode: .common)
}

@objc func printAnimationProgress() {
    print(button.layer.presentation()!.position.x)
}
*/
```

---

That said, `CAMediaTimingFunction`s are just [cubic Bezier curves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Cubic_B%C3%A9zier_curves), so it is possible to calculate the animation progress without actually running the animation too. As you can see from the wikipedia page, the curve are parametrically defined by four control points, which we can get using [`getControlPoint`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/camediatimingfunction/1522057-getcontrolpoint).

After that, we can get the equation of the y coordinates of the curve in terms of the parameter t. But t is not time here. Instead, the x coordinate of the curve is the time of the animation. So we need to express t in terms of the x coordinates. We can already express x in terms of t with a cubic equation, using the control points (see equations on Wikipedia), so we just need to solve the equation. [This](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#yforx) shows you where to start.

Finally, we just need to plug in the x, which is the time, to get the parameter t, and then plug that into the equation for the y coordinates.

We can write a function like this:

```
func getCallableFunction(fromTimingFunction function: CAMediaTimingFunction) -> (Float) -> Float {
    // Each *pair* of elements in cps store a control point.
    // the elements at even indices store the x coordinates
    // the elements at odd indices store the y coordinates
    var cps = Array(repeating: Float(0), count: 8)
    cps.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { pointer in
        for i in 0..<4 {
            function.getControlPoint(at: i, values: &pointer[i * 2])
        }
    }

    return { x in
        // assuming the curve doesn't do weird things like loop around on itself, this only has one real root
        // coefficients got from https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#yforx
        // implementation of cubicSolve from https://gist.github.com/kieranb662/b85aada0b1c03a06ad2f83a0291d7243
        let t = Float(cubicSolve(
            a: Double(-cps[0] + cps[2] * 3 - cps[4] * 3 + cps[6]),
            b: Double(cps[0] * 3 - cps[2] * 6 + cps[4] * 3),
            c: Double(-cps[0] * 3 + cps[2] * 3),
            d: Double(cps[0] - x)
        ).first(where: \.isReal)!.real)
        
        // getting y from t, see equation on Wikipedia
        return powf(1 - t, 3) * cps[1] +
                powf(1 - t, 2) * t * cps[3] * 3 +
                (1 - t) * t * t * cps[5] * 3 +
                t * t * t * cps[7]
    }
}
```

Note that I used a cubic solver from [this gist](https://gist.github.com/kieranb662/b85aada0b1c03a06ad2f83a0291d7243), which calculates all the roots. Feel free use another, faster, algorithm.

Example usage for the `default` timing function:

```
let function = getCallableFunction(fromTimingFunction: .init(name: .default))
for i in stride(from: Float(0), through: 1, by: 0.05) {
    let result = function(i)
    print(result) // this prints a result between 0 and 1
}
```

Plotting the results on a graph looks like this:

[image]

This is very similar to the shape as the graph shown in the documentation of [`default`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/camediatimingfunctionname/1521854-default).

To apply this to a particular animation, simply linearly scale the time and output of the function. For example, for an animation with duration 2 and animates between 0 and 300:

```
let result = function(time / 2) * 300
```

Comment: I am missing this: `Cannot find 'cubicSolve' in scope`

Comment: Oh, my bad, sorry. I solved that issue but now I do not know how to use `getCallableFunction` I never see the function like that, can you show the use case?

Comment: Thanks for help and answering, last question do you not think this much math and calculation for an animation data is too much? I mean calculating this much data would take time and delay on animation result, I am not saying apple doing this way but apple doing more or less this kind of thing, even if we say this is not heavy to cpu, how we could mach the animation resolution with device refresh rate? I mean we can make animation data for 60  Hz or 90 Hz but how should know which one we need? it is getting so complicated in this way, the thing that I wanted was

Comment: to access this animation data without putting this all works, I just wanted read all animation value from `let animation = CABasicAnimation()` because that would be lighter and faster and correct about screen refresh rate.

Comment: Exactly, I have an existing animation playing and i want look inside the values and print them while playing.

Comment: Please do not omit anything from this current answer I need them for lather study.

Comment: @HelloCodes I have added the display link approach. Regarding "calculating this much data would take time and delay on animation result", I think there is a lot of room to improve my code. For one, the `cubicSolve` I'm using finds all 3 roots, when this needs is the single real root. This stuff can also probably be done in the GPU where it can be done in parallel, and it doesn't need to be *too* precise. In short, there is probably a *lot* of opportunities for optimisations.